# matrix multiplication in 4D by eigen tensor

Tags: c++11, eigen, large-language-model

I'm working on cpp implementation of llm by eigen::tensor.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

int main() {
    const int batch_size = 1;
    const int num_queries = 40;
    const int dim_query = 6;
    const int dim_key = 128;

    // Example initialization of query_states and key_states
    Eigen::Tensor<float, 4> query_states(batch_size, num_queries, dim_query, dim_key);
    Eigen::Tensor<float, 4> key_states(batch_size, num_queries, dim_key, dim_query);

    // Initialize tensors with some values (for demonstration)
    // ... (initialization code)

    // Specify dimensions for contraction
    Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<int>, 1> product_dims = { Eigen::IndexPair<int>(3, 2) };

    // Perform tensor contraction (batched matrix multiplication)
    Eigen::Tensor<float, 4> attn_weights = query_states.contract(key_states, product_dims);

    // attn_weights now has the shape (1, 40, 6, 6)
    
    // ... (rest of the code)
}
```

Why there is an error call in the line of "Eigen::Tensor<float, 4> attn_weights = query_states.contract(key_states, product_dims);" as "In template: static assertion failed due to requirement 'TensorContractionOp<const std::arrayEigen::IndexPair<int, 1>, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 4, 0, long>, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 4, 0, long>, const Eigen::NoOpOutputKernel>::NumDimensions == TensorBase<Eigen::Tensor<float, 4, 0, long>, 1>::NumDimensions': Number_of_dimensions_must_match"

The output should be in  (1, 40, 6, 6). I want to know how to achieve this multiplication.